# Change view path of package in runtime

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel Version : `5.7`

I'm using [thekordy/ticktit](https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit) package for ticketing system , and it support two bootstrap version .

And its set the view package path base on the bootstrap field in database .

```php
//in the package service Provider 

$viewsDirectory = __DIR__.'/Views/bootstrap3';            
if (Setting::grab('bootstrap_version') == '4') {
    $viewsDirectory = __DIR__.'/Views/bootstrap4';
}
// the grab get bootstrap version from database

//and then set the package viewDirectory
$this->loadViewsFrom($viewsDirectory, 'ticketit');
```

I have two panels with two different bootstrap version and want to set bootstrap version base on users roles but as you know i can't check the authenticated user in `serviceProvider.php`.

I got stuck , how can i handle this?

Thanks.